# Django - submit multiple forms in a view

Tags: python, django

I have two forms in my views, when I hit on save it's not working properly, when I want to display on my templates what I saved not showing as expected.

Here's what I have:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    queryset = Personinfo.objects.all()
    queryset2 = Person.objects.all()
    qs = chain(queryset,queryset2)
    form = personform(request.POST or None)
    form2 = personinfoform(request.POST or None)
    context = {
    "queryset": queryset,
    "queryset2": queryset2,
    "qs": qs,
    "form2":form2,
    "form":form,
    }
    form2_valid = form2.is_valid()
    form_valid = form.is_valid()
    if form2_valid and form_valid:
        a = form2.save()
        b= form.save(commit=False)
        b.ForeignkeytoA = a
        b.save()
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{form2.as_p}}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Save!" />
</form>

            <table >
             <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Hobbies</th>

            </tr>
            {% for item in qs  %}
            <tr> 
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td> #form2
                <td>{{ item.address }}</td> #form1
                <td>{{ item.phone_number }}</td> #form1
                <td>{{ item.address }}</td> #form1
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

**models.py**

```
class Personinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name





class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Personinfo)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    hobbies =models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person
```

my output:

[image: Click here]

As you can see my table isn't showing my items as expected. 
Is there a possible way to show every item in the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors are present. If I understand right, you're expecting the data from a `Person` instance and the data from its accompanying `PersonInfo` instance to print on the same line. However, you're trying to achieve this by using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), which is not joining the querysets based on their relationship, but rather concatenating them blindly.

So if `Person.objects.all()` returns a queryset which contains the following data

```
id  person   address   phone_number    hobbies   
1      1         a         a             a
2      2         5         5             5
```

and `PersonInfo.objects.all()` returns a queryset which contains

```
id   Name 
1    aaa      
2    aa
```

`chain` combines them as

```
id  person  name   address   phone_number    hobbies
1           aaa
2           aa
1      1             a           a             a
2      2             5           5             5
```

Instead, you should utilize the relationship between the models. If you pass only the `Person` queryset as context to your template, you could write

```
{% for p in persons %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ p.person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.phone_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.hobbies }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

--

Additionally you are setting the `Personinfo` related instance incorrectly when you save your forms. By using `b.ForeignkeytoA` you are creating a new variable as a member of the object `b` called `ForeignkeytoA`, which has nothing to do with the `Personinfo` relationship. To set the related `Personinfo`, you should reference the name of the foreign key field, `person`. To correct this, that segment should be

```
# ...
b = form.save(commit = False)
b.person = a
b.save()
# ...
```

Comment: `<td>{{p.person.name}} </td>` not working for me, I tried passing only `Person` as you suggested, everything works ok except by `name`

Comment: Try `<td>{{ p.person.id }}</td>` and see if it prints an id.

Comment: Also, is `b.ForeignkeytoA = a` the way it's written in your code? This will set a new variable called `ForeignkeytoA` under the python object `b`, not set the `person` foreign key to the object `a`. It should be `b.person = a`.

Comment: What about the `ForeignkeytoA`?

Comment: you meant `b.person=a` under `b.save()`?

Comment: Instead of `b.ForeignkeytoA = a` it should be `b.person = a` then `b.save()`, otherwise you aren't associating the objects, which would explain why you can't reference `.person`.

Comment: Yes, that worked exactly as I expected. Thank you a lot!